# how to make mat radio button selected by default by displaying a key and sending value associated with the key

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have some radio buttons. I want to select one option by default. I have read somewhere that [checked] should work.
I have made the data structure like that but it is not working.

```
  <mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason" >
  <mat-radio-button class="exmple-radio-button" *ngFor="let season of seasons" [value]="season.value" [checked]="season.checked">
    {{season.key}}-{{season.checked}}
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<div class="example-selected-value">Your favorite season is: {{favoriteSeason}}</div>
```

ts

```
  export class RadioNgModelExample {
      favoriteSeason = '';
      seasons = [
        {
    key: 'Winter',
    checked: false,
    value: 1
        },
           {
    key: 'Spring',
    checked: true,
     value: 2
        },{
        key: 'Summer',
    checked: false,
     value: 3  
        },{
          key: 'Autumn',
    checked: false,
     value: 4      
        }];
    }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drf2s5-55tcr1?file=app/radio-ng-model-example.ts)

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the `favoriteSeason` variable. In your example you are only setting the type and not the value.
You need `favoriteSeason = 'Spring'`. This initializes the value of `favoriteSeason` (the ngModel used by the radio button group) to the string `'Spring'`.

`favoriteSeason: 'Spring'` is a type declaration. You're declaring that property to be of type `'Spring'`. This is most likely unintended. You could include a type declaration as well: `favoriteSeason: string = 'Spring'`, but this is also unnecessary since the type can be inferred.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `[(ngModel)]="favoriteSeason"` to `<mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group">` and it will work.

Or merely change your Ts file to :

```
export class RadioNgModelExample {
  favoriteSeason: string ;
  seasons = [
    {
      key: 'Winter',
      checked: false
    },
    {
      key: 'Spring',
      checked: true
    },{
      key: 'Summer',
      checked: false  
    },{
      key: 'Autumn',
      checked: false      
    }];

  constructor() {
    this.favoriteSeason= 'Spring'

    // **As well as this**
    // this.favoriteSeason= this.seasons[1].key;

  }
}
```

[**Here the updated stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-drf2s5-yyfavx?file=app%2Fradio-ng-model-example.ts)

Comment: I need ngModel because I am using template driven form

Comment: Recheck the answer then,  @HumbleDolt

Comment: Hello @selem mn, I am sending different values. can you please check my updated stackblitz?